# Dart streams - skipWhile not skipping events

Tags: dart

Doesn't seem like skipWhile is doing anything... or am I understanding this wrong?

Below code... I am expecting skipWhile to remove two entries!

Dart version (from flutter doctor): `Dart version 2.9.0 (build 2.9.0-10.0.dev 7706afbcf5)`

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

class Car {
  final String name;
  final bool active;
  final int wheels;

  Car({this.name, this.active=true, this.wheels=4});
}

void main() {
  test("Check skipWhile", () {
    List dataSet = [
      Car(name: "Thunder", active: false),
      Car(name: "Lightening", active: false),
      Car(name: "Dinky", wheels: 3),
      Car(name: "Camry"),
      Car(name: "Outback"),
    ];

    List activeCars = dataSet.skipWhile((car) => car.active).toList();

    expect(activeCars.length, 3);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the documentation for [`skipWhile`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.2/dart-core/Iterable/skipWhile.html) you will see:

> Returns an Iterable that skips leading elements while test is satisfied.

So it just skips the leading elements and not all elements.

What you properly want instead is [`where`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.2/dart-core/Iterable/where.html) which does:

> Returns a new lazy Iterable with all elements that satisfy the predicate test.

So if I change your `skipWhile` to `where` in your example, I will now get the length of 3:

```
class Car {
  final String name;
  final bool active;
  final int wheels;

  Car({this.name, this.active = true, this.wheels = 4});
}

void main() {
  final dataSet = [
    Car(name: "Thunder", active: false),
    Car(name: "Lightening", active: false),
    Car(name: "Dinky", wheels: 3),
    Car(name: "Camry"),
    Car(name: "Outback"),
  ];

  final activeCars = dataSet.where((car) => car.active).toList();

  print(activeCars.length); // 3
}
```

Comment: Than you for the explanation.